# how to get images from web service JSON?

Tags: iphone

How to get image and show in iphone from json webservice response. as i get response very well.

this is part of my web service response:

```
{

        "Campaign Id" = 215;
        "Campaign Name" = "Denivit 2in1 Extreme White";
        "Final Report Link" = "https://www.buzzador.com/report2/index.php?sid=29282&token=1731692044";
        "Flash Report Count" = 1;
        "Last Date Registration" = "2008-05-18";
        "Link for checking delivery status" = "";
        "Product image" = "denivit.jpg";
        Status = reported;
    },
```

In which product image contain image url....now how to print this image in iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to download the image using

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourImageURLString]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Now you can use assign the `image` to an `UIImageView` object. Since this is a blocking operation, you should to start this in a background thread and send the UI updates back to the main thread.

If you are interested in parsing `JSON` files, there are some good libraries out there one of which is [`TouchJSON`](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON).

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"yourimage"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];
```